# get string between tag in basic4android

Tags: java, regex

hey guys i tried to get string between `<description> my text </description>`
so wrote this one

```
Sub JobDone (job As HttpJob)
ProgressDialogHide
If reciver.Success = True Then
Dim text() As String
text=Regex.Matcher("<description>(.*)</description>",reciver.GetString)
Log(text.Length)
For i=0 To text.Length-1
ListView1.AddSingleLine(text(i))
Next
Else
ToastMessageShow("failed",True)
End If
reciver.Release
End Sub
```

but this got error

```
src\b4a\example\main.java:379: error: inconvertible types
_text = (String[])(anywheresoftware.b4a.keywords.Common.Regex.Matcher("<description>(.*)</description>",mostCurrent._reciver._getstring()).getObject());
                  ^
  required: String[]
  found:    Matcher
```

Comment: The error suggests that you have declared `text` as a string but are trying to assign an object (`Matcher`) to it.  Check the documentation for `Matcher` for a suitable method to return a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, `Regex.Matcher` returns an object of type `Matcher`, but your variable `text` expects a `String[]`. You need to extract the strings from the matcher, so you can put them into `text`.

From the [B4A docs](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/help/regularexpressions.html), you would need to do something like this:

```
Dim Matcher1 As Matcher
Matcher1 = Regex.Matcher("<description>(.*)</description>", reciver.GetString)
Do While Matcher1.Find
    ListView1.AddSingleLine(Matcher1.Match)
Loop
```

This would still match `<description>` and `</description>` though. Using regex is not the best option in this case, a [proper XML parsing library](http://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/xml-parsing-with-the-xmlsax-library.6866/) would probably be better.

Comment: thanks for your answer yeah i found the problem but my question still is how can i get that text between those tags

Comment: ok i changed  Dim Matcher1 As Matcher
Matcher1 = Regex.Matcher("<description>(.*)</description>", reciver.GetString)
Do While Matcher1.Find
    ListView1.AddSingleLine(Matcher1.Match)
Loop  but <description> is in string